# edX provisioning Issue: get stuck at, TASK: [edxapp | checkout edx-platform repo into {{edxapp_code_dir}}]

Tags: python, django, git, github, edx

I am trying to install [edX developer stack](https://github.com/edx/configuration/wiki/edX-Developer-Stack#installing-the-edx-developer-stack) in my local system. I am facing the issue: [edx-platform checkout failure](https://github.com/edx/configuration/wiki/edX-Developer-Stack#provisioning-issues) but difference is that it's stuck at the first line:

```
==> default: TASK: [edxapp | checkout edx-platform repo into {{edxapp_code_dir}}] **********
```

and my local system gets very slow. I've checked the remote origin is set to  https://github.com/edx/edx-platform.git. Any suggestion/help on this topic? I am using `Ubuntu-14.04` with 2GB memory.

Comment: System gets slow because the VM requires 2gb of ram and my machine is also 2gb.

Comment: Don't worry, my machine has 4GB of RAM and my edX VM is set to 1GB only, and everything is fine with that. So better set your VM to 1GB otherwise your whole machine will be slow.

Comment: Did you read this? https://github.com/edx/configuration/wiki/edX-Developer-Stack#provisioning-issues

Comment: why down vote? It's a perfectly valid and well researched question.

Comment: reducing the memory of VM made it work. I made it 1gb. thanks @StéphaneBruckert.

Comment: That's great. I have made that a real answer which you can accept if you want. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, the provisioning got stuck because of a memory issue.

When using a Virtual Machine, it's better to not allocate the maximum possible memory to it, otherwise your host machine won't have anymore air to breathe and couldn't do fundamental stuff anymore. A VM usually tends to use as much memory as you will allow it.

```
Hardware memory  |  VM memory
       4GB      ->   max. 2GB
       2GB      ->   max. 1GB
```

Because I found my 4GB host machine quite slow with a 2GB VM, I am now using 1GB on the VM which is squarely enough to run edX.